# Observing AWS App Runner 429s

Tags: amazon-web-services, metrics

During performance testing we're seeing 429s from App Runner. The body of the response will say "Max queue length has been reached". I know this is a known issue and it's described here in detail: https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/224

My question is, how can I more easily observe this? I'd like to be able to look at a metric in AWS that'll show me the 429s thrown by App Runner. The closest I've seen is a metric in the dashboard labeled "4xx errors" but of course that's too broad.